# Divide by 0 error in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have an SSRS Report with a lot of calculations. I have a function with the report that supposed to take care divide by 0 error but I still get the error.
The function code is
` Function Divide(Numerator as Double, Denominator as Double)

```
If Denominator = 0 Then

Return 0

Else

Return Numerator/Denominator

End If

End Function `
```

I also have a expression that is
`=Code.Divide(ReportItems!Textbox41.Value, Fields!mnypotientalRentTotal.Value)'
I have no idea how to fix the divide by 0 error any ideas would be great.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variables/columns? The error might be due to implicit conversion (e.g. `Denominator` being an empty string (so it doesn't pass the `=0` check) but upon having `Numerator/Denominator` to be calculated, the empty string is converted to a number (0).

Answer (score 0):

probably yua are not handlying 'NULL' values.
Try this:

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Numerator As Double, ByVal Denominator As Double)
If IsNothing(Denominator) Or Denominator = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Numerator/Denominator 
End If
End Function
```